# update/join multiple columns on lookup table dynamically

Tags: r, data.table

Here is a toy example of a table `unit` with two unit columns that I want to join dynamically on a lookup table `mult`. I can do this writing it all out:

```
unit[mult, mul1 := i.multiplier, on = c(uni1 = 'unit') ]
unit[mult, mul2 := i.multiplier, on = c(uni2 = 'unit') ]
```

However, I want to do this dynamically, since in my real `unit` table, the number of columns can vary. Can I perform this join dynamically?

I tried this, but I struggle with the `on =` argument:

```
for (j in seq_along(names(unit))) {
  col = names(unit)[j]
  unit[mult, paste0('mul', j) := i.multiplier, on = c(col = 'unit') ]
}
```

Data:

```
unit = data.table(
uni1 = c("ug", "mg", "ppm", "kg", "kg", "uM",
           "mg", "lb", "%", "g"),
  uni2 = c("L", "L", NA, "ha", "ha", NA,
           "kg", "acre", NA, "ha")
)
mult = data.table(
  unit = c("ug", "mg", "g", "kg", "L", "ppm", "uM",
           "ha", "acre", "%", "lb"),
  multiplier = c(1e-06, 0.001, 1, 1000,
                 1, 1000, 1e-06, 10000, 4050, 1e+07, 453.592)
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tinkered a little more and came up with this solution, making use of `setkey()`:

```
setkey(mult, 'unit')
for (j in seq_along(names(unit))) {
  col = names(unit)[j]
  setkeyv(unit, col)
  unit[mult, paste0('mul', j) := i.multiplier ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to joining is to match corresponding `mult` entires using a function applied column-wise using `.SD`.

```
mulcol = paste0('mul', 1:ncol(unit))

unit[, (mulcol) := lapply(.SD, function(x){
  sapply(x, function(y) mult[unit == y, multiplier])
})]
```

Output:

```
> unit
    uni1 uni2        mul1  mul2
 1:   ug    L 1.00000e-06     1
 2:   mg    L 1.00000e-03     1
 3:  ppm <NA> 1.00000e+03      
 4:   kg   ha 1.00000e+03 10000
 5:   kg   ha 1.00000e+03 10000
 6:   uM <NA> 1.00000e-06      
 7:   mg   kg 1.00000e-03  1000
 8:   lb acre 4.53592e+02  4050
 9:    % <NA> 1.00000e+07      
10:    g   ha 1.00000e+00 10000
```

The only difference is that nonexisting `uni2`-values evaluate to `numeric(0)` instead of `NA`.